# Evil-mode text objects not working in python.el's python-mode

Tags: python, evil

This only happens in python-mode. When I try to use a text object to, for example, change everything inside or around some brackets (eg `ci(`) it instead edits the first line of the file. So if I have this:

`from somewhere import something
something("hello")`

and my cursor is on the hello and I type `ci(` then it changes to:

`fg
something("hello")`

with my cursor between the f and the g. This happens no matter what else is in the file.

Try to edit inside quotes (eg `ci"`)also fails but in a different way. It just drops into insert mode and leaves the contents unchanged.

Any ideas where I should start with tracking down the source of this issue?

Comment: Can't reproduce this here.  Bisect your configuration by starting out with `emacs -Q` and enabling `evil` manually to find a good state, then recursively comment out your init file to find the offending part of it.  If even `emacs -Q` behaves faulty and upgrading packages doesn't help either, hand in a detailed bug report at [their issue tracker](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues).

Comment: Did something clobber your keybindings?  When in normal state, do `C-h k c`: it should be bound to `evil-change`.  Hit `c` so that you're in operator-pending state.  Hit `C-h k i` -- it should still be waiting for you to finish the text object.  Hit `(` to complete the text object: it should be bound to `evil-inner-paren`.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. I'm not even sure what I did that fixed it in the end (should have tracked that better so I could answer the question!)

Comment: // , @ThomasParslow, yeah, I code Python and use Emacs Evil-mode, too. *scared*